# UpdatePanels - Controls outside are re-rendered?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, updatepanel

I have rather a complex UI page with several UpdatePanels nested. All of them are set to `UpdateMode = "Conditional"`

I have a listbox outside all the updatepanels. It's strange how there's a flicker on these listboxes when any buttons within the UpdatePanels are clicked.

My understanding was if the mode is conditional, this should not be happening.

Any ideas on where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: I've experienced this before on an unpatched version of IE6 (I don't think the fact that it was unpatched was the problem, I couldn't figure out what the problem was at the time). What browser(s) are you experiencing this in?

Answer (score 2):

On the parent UpdatePanels, set the ChildrenAsTriggers property to False and also look at using the Triggers element of the UpdatePanels you want to update to specify your triggers explicitly.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTrigger" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but the browser might be doing this when it's re-rendering things within the other UpdatePanels.  I wonder if you put everything inside a "global" UpdatePanel if this behavior will stop.